# How resolve a replaceAll of a replaceAll

Tags: java, search, replaceall

I have a little problem.
I have a text that i have to read in browser several time.
Everytime, I open this text, automatically start a replaceAll that i wrote.
It's very simple, basic but that problem is that when i do replace next time (every time i read this text) i have a replaceAll of replaceAll.
For example i have in the text:

```
XIII
```

I want to replace it whith

```
<b>XIII</b>
```

with:

```
txt.replaceAll("XIII","<b>XIII</b>")
```

The first time it's everything fine, but then, when i read again the text, it become:

```
<b><b>XIII</b></b>
```

It's a stupid problem, but i start now with Java.
I read that is possibile use regex.Could someone post a little example?

Thanks, and excuse me for my poor english.

Comment: why you want to replace the content which is already replaced?

Comment: you need an exit creiteria, one `<b>XIII` occured exit replace process

Comment: Why do you need to do the `replaceAll` several times? It looks like it is necessary for you to do it exactly once. It is probably better for you to solve that problem: Make sure you do the `replaceAll` once and only once.

Answer (score 3):

You need negative lookbehind to prevent a match on an already marked-up string:

```
txt.replaceAll("(?<!>)XIII","<b>XIII</b");
```

This expression looks a bit convoluted, but this is how it decomposes:

- `(?<! ... )` is the template for the negative lookbehind;
- `>` is the specific character we want to make sure doesn't occur in front of your string.

I should also warn you that fixing up HTML with regex's usually turns into a diabolic cycle of  upgrading the regex to handle yet another special case, only to see it fail on the next one. It ends up with a monster that nobody can read, let alone improve.

Comment: I assume `XIII` could be surrounded by other tags such as `<a href="...">XIII</a>`

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov Regex solutions to HTML problems are always very limited. I could easily add a `<b` there, but that would just slightly postpone the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's a really fast solution. Do the opposite Replace before doing your own.

Let me show:

```
txt.replaceAll("<b>XIII</b>","XIII").replaceAll("XIII","<b>XIII</b>")
```

So you first turn your `<b>` into normal and than turn it back with `<b>` and it will achieve the same result without adding the new level of `<b>`.

Answer (score -1):

What about this:

```
txt = txt.replaceAll ("XIII", "<b>XIII</b>").
    replceAll ("<b><b>", "<b>").replaceAll ("</b></b>", "</b>");
```

I think `<b><b>` and `</b></b>` do not have much sense in HTML, so it is fine to remove duplicates even in other places.